# Generic method <?> Type Arguments

Tags: java, generics

In a library for charts I found the following class:

```
public class SeriesBuilder<T> {
    private T[] data;

    private SeriesBuilder() {
    }

    public static SeriesBuilder<?> get() {
        return new SeriesBuilder();
    }
    
    public SeriesBuilder<T> withData(T... data) {
        this.data = data;
        return this;
    }

    public Series<T> build() {
        Series<T> series = new Series<T>();
        series.setData(data);
        return series;
    }
}
```

Using code:

```
SeriesBuilder.get()
             .withData(<<<<<???>>>>)
             .build()
```

I'm not able to find out how to use the class because of the <?> Type. I can't find an argument that fullfills the signature. How to use this?

Comment: `null` is the only argument which will work. Whoever wrote that SeriesBuilder doesn't know how to use generics. Signature should be `public static <U> SeriesBuilder<U> get() { return new SeriesBuilder<>(); }`

Comment: @Eklavya note that the constructor is private. I'm forced to use get().

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not able to find out how to use the class because of the <?> Type. I can't find an argument that fullfills the signature. How to use this?

You pretty much can't use it.  There is no way to obtain a `SeriesBuilder` instance except via `SeriesBuilder.get()`, and the type parameter of an instance that you obtain that way is unknown -- in fact, what `get` actually instantiates is the raw type.  You should be able to produce a series of `null`s if you wish.

There cannot even be any subclasses of `SeriesBuilder` (that might be more usable), because its only constructor is private.

Without putting too fine a point on it, this `SeriesBuilder` is pretty much an abomination.  There is an argument to be made for preferring factory methods (such as `SeriesBuilder.get()`) over constructors, but that implementation is terrible.  In addition to the type parameter issues, it does not initialize the resulting object to a valid state.  That has to be done separately via `withData()`, so what is the point of `get()` supposed to be?

I'm inclined to think that whoever wrote that was looking for something that would have been better expressed via this variation on `withData()`:

```
    public static <T> SeriesBuilder<T> withData(T ... data) {
        SeriesBuilder<T> builder = new SeriesBuilder<>();

        builder.data = data;
        return builder;
    }
```

You might use that as

```
SomeType item1 = /* value */;
SomeType item2 = /* value */;
SomeType item3 = /* value */;

Series<SomeType> series =
        SeriesBuilder.withData(item1, item2, item3)
                     .build();
```